# Getting Vim Function to call itself according to time

Tags: vim

what am i doing wrong here? nothing happens when I get into vim.

[image]

Here is my code!

```
colorscheme default
let g:Favcolorschemes = ["darkblue", "morning", "shine", "evening"] 
function SetTimeOfDayColors()
  " currentHour will be 0, 1, 2, or 3
  let g:CurrentHour = (strftime("%H") + 0) / 6
  if  g:colors_name !~ g:Favcolorschemes[g:CurrentHour]
    execute "colorscheme " . g:Favcolorschemes[g:CurrentHour]
    echo "execute " "colorscheme " . g:Favcolorschemes[g:CurrentHour]
    redraw
  endif
endfunction
set statusline=%<%t%h%m%r\ \ %a\ %{strftime(\"%c\")}%=0x%B\
    \\ line:%1,\ \ col:%c%V\ %P
set statusline+= \ %{SetTimeOfDayColors()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Through `SetTimeOfDayColors()`, you're effectively executing a `:colorscheme` command from the `'statusline'` expression. Looks like that isn't possible / effective. However, for me, this **minimal example does work** (GVIM 7.3.823 on Windows):

```
fun! Foo()
    colorscheme blue
endfun
set stl=%{Foo()}
```

(Sorry, I don't want to spend the time to typewrite your code off your screenshot.)

#### Possible workarounds

In `SetTimeOfDayColors()`, only update a (global) variable containing the colorscheme name, and let an `:autocmd` that runs frequently (e.g. on `CursorHold`) do the actual `:colorscheme` change.

Comment: Is there an easy way to paste code from vim to here? would be happy to do that if possible.

Comment: `V}"*y` should copy the text from the cursor to the next paragraph into your clipboard.  `:h msdos-copy-paste`